# Keep data in string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to c#. I must define multiple arrays to keep `datagridview` data.
How can I define multiple string arrays defined in one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can simply use `ArrayList` to get what u want

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to keep data in string array? use [datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) or [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your custom object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). Just replace `int` with `string`s.

```
// Two-dimensional array. 
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// The same array with dimensions specified. 
int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// A similar array with string elements. 
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" },
                                        { "five", "six" } };

// Three-dimensional array. 
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                 { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
// The same array with dimensions specified. 
int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                       { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this By using [Jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
string[] a1 = { "1", "2", "3"};
string[] a2 = { "4", "5", "6"};


string[][] arr = {a1, a2};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list for that as bellow. But why do you use string arrays? instead of this you can use class with defined properties.

```
List<string[]> asdf = new List<string[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Jagged arrays.

Take a look at this, it contains the explanation and examples of what they are and how to use them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Just replace int with string and you are good to go.

Example taken form the link:

```
class ArrayTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare the array of two elements: 
        int[][] arr = new int[2][];

        // Initialize the elements:
        arr[0] = new int[5] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        arr[1] = new int[4] { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

        // Display the array elements: 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.Write("Element({0}): ", i);

            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
            {
                System.Console.Write("{0}{1}", arr[i][j], j == (arr[i].Length - 1) ? "" : " ");
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();            
        }
        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/* Output:
    Element(0): 1 3 5 7 9
    Element(1): 2 4 6 8
*/
```